# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem does not contain a definition for Sender...?

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to use the following code sample from msdn:

```
private string GetSenderSMTPAddress(Outlook.MailItem mail)
{
    string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";
    if (mail == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    if (mail.SenderEmailType == "EX")
    {
        //This rows gives an error:
        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem does not contain a definition for Sender
        Outlook.AddressEntry sender = mail.Sender; 
        if (sender != null)
        {
            //Now we have an AddressEntry representing the Sender
            if (sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry ||
                sender.AddressEntryUserType == Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
            {
                //Use the ExchangeUser object PrimarySMTPAddress
                Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = sender.GetExchangeUser();
                return (exchUser != null) ? exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress : null;
            }
            return sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) as string;
        }
        return null;
    }
    return mail.SenderEmailAddress;
}
```

But for some reason I'm getting this compile error:

```
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' does not contain a definition for 'Sender' 
and no extension method 'Sender' accepting a first argument of type 
'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I'm using winforms with framework 3.5, wat can I do...?

Comment: `Sender` was added in Office 2010. Are you using the correct version of Office Interop?

Comment: How can I check it ?
And how can I change to use it if I;m not using it now ?

Comment: You have added a reference to the interop library. Go to the project References and check.

Comment: It doesn't specify the outlook version as 2010.
It only says "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"

Comment: It does specify the library version. This directly relates to the Office version, which you should have been able to [quickly find out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7750424/11683).

Comment: So it seems that version 12 is for office 2007, so I need version 14. I do have ofiice 2010 on my computer, so how can I ger version 14 if it doesn't appear in the "Add Reference" window ?

Comment: Please use Google for simple questions that can be answered with the first Google result: [How to: Install Office Primary Interop Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw.aspx)

Comment: plus 1 as there is really no reason to downvote this question.

Answer (score 1):

See [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) . It supports earlier Outlook versions.

P.S. You may check the Outlook interop reference by choosing it in the Solutions Explorer window. In the Properties window will find its version.